# Unable to login to Self API Workspace

Tags: amadeus

I can no more access the Self API Workspace. I get the message:

Authentication failed. Please check your username, password and second authentication factors (like Access Code or Digital DNA) before trying again.

What is this second authentication factor (like Access Code or Digital DNA) ?

I reset my password, got the activation email, clicked and got confirmed that the new password is now active. Butt still cannot login. Is there any known problem today? Til yesterday login mades no problem.

Eric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are informed about the problem as they posted an announcement:

Announcement:
We are currently experiencing technical difficulties with the sign-in and actively working to address the issue. Be assured that the ongoing matter does not impact API runtime traffic.

Update: The problem has been fixed on Amadeus' side. Login is now possible.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).